# Successful Count not being updated for Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function with a Service Bus trigger which has had a lot of successful executions

However, when I go to the portal and look at the function the success count is 0

Has anyone ever had this?

I am using V3 of functions

[image]

Paul

Comment: What do the logs tell you? There must be reason why the executions are marked as not successful.

Comment: My messages are being handled and the function is behaving as I want so there is no reason I can see why successful executions are not logged.  The error ones are fine, I know about them and have fixed the issue that caused them

Comment: @Paul - could you please post your 'function.json' file and Application insight logs so we can look at the configuration and dependencies.

Comment: Which app insight logs?